# Google Chrome DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_BAD_SECURE_CONFIG error

Tags: google-chrome, dns

I wanted to change DNS server on macOS 10.14.6 by going to System Preferences -> Network -> Advanced..., and adding 8.8.8.8 in the DNS tab. Since then, Chrome gives me a
`DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_BAD_SECURE_CONFIG` error.

First I returned to the previous DNS settings (putting 192.168.1.1 in place of 8.8.8.8). Since then I tried switching my router off/on. I cleared the Chrome DNS cache as explained in [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/203674/how-to-clear-flush-the-dns-cache-in-google-chrome). I cleared browsing data (history, cache, cookies) on Chrome. I stopped and restarted the mDNSResponder service.

From the terminal, both `ping` and `curl` work fine. Other browsers (Safari) work fine. Why do I see this error, and how do I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

If you have checked all DNS settings but still got this error, you could take a look at the Chrome Secure DNS to see if this setting had switched on.

To turn Chrome Secure DNS on or off:
Open Chrome.

At the top right, tap More [image: Organize] and then Settings.

Under “Privacy and security,” tap Security.

Turn Use Secure DNS on or off.